# Changing hyperlink color with parameter passing

Tags: jsp, href

I want to change the hyperlink color, but when I try to do that, the `style=color:white` parameter is also sent by parameter!

But i want just `<%=rs.getString("isbn")%>` be the parameter.

```
<a href="doBuy?isbn=<%=resultset.getString("isbn")%> style=color:white"> Add To Card </a>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: style='color:white;'

Comment: @bencripps Not worked, Now is `...?isbn=3652 style='color:white'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have mistake with quotation marks.

See below proper code:

```
<a href="doBuy?isbn=<%=resultset.getString("isbn")%>" style="color:white"> Add To Card </a>
```

You can change order of attributes if you want (it doesnt matter):

```
<a style="color:white" href="doBuy?isbn=<%=resultset.getString("isbn")%>"> Add To Card </a>
```